# How to use filter_input on a checkbox group?

Tags: php, user-input, sanitization

I've got a group of checkboxes and am having trouble seeing how I can use filter_input to retrieve their values.

My data looks like this (from `print_r($_GET)`):

```
Array ( 
  [Keywords] => Array ( 
    [0] => Dairy 
  ) 
  [Diet] => Array ( 
    [0] => Diabetes Appropriate 
    [1] => Healthy Weight 
  ) 
  [Regional] => Array ( 
    [0] => Greek 
    [1] => Mediterranean 
  )
)
```

This code..

```
// the specific categories I want to retrieve
$cat_names = array(
  "Regional",
  "Diet",
  "Keywords"
);

// filter new category data
$cats = array();
foreach( $cat_names as $c ){
  $cats[ $c ] = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $c);
}
```

..produces this:

```
array(4) (
  [Regional] => (bool) false
  [Diet] => (bool) false
  [Keywords] => (bool) false
)
```

..but was hoping for this:

```
array(4) (
  [Regional] => array(2) ('Greek', 'Mediterranean')
  [Diet] => array(2) ( 'Diabetes Appropriate', 'Healthy Weight')
  [Keywords] => array(1) ('Dairy')
)
```

I haven't worked in php outside of a framework in a while - how do I do this?

Comment: What's the value of `INPUT_GET`?

Comment: Edited question to show data.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a solution to a similar problem I have when I found your post, I did come up with this solution though...

You can add these filters in your filter_input function:

```
$cats[$c] = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $c, FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
```

Instead of FILTER_DEFAULT, you can sanitize the way you want.

However, if you have simple association `some_category => some_value` that is not an array, you'll end up with an empty `$cats['some_category']`

For example if your $_GET contains something like this:

```
Array ( 
  [Regional] => Array ( 
    [0] => Greek 
    [1] => Mediterranean 
  )
  [some_category] => 'some value'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is a simple case of using `array_intersect_key()` with the help of `array_flip()`.

The result of `$cats = array_intersect_key( $_GET, array_flip($cat_names) );` should be exactly what you're looking for.

[PHP - Array Intersect Key](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) - [PHP - Array Flip](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

Comment: I'm unclear on how this helps me get sanitized values from a checkbox group. This is just modifying the array structure, isn't it?